# TypeError: dtype datetime64[ns] cannot be converted to timedelta64[ns]

Tags: pandas, datetime, timedelta

I have a column of years from the [sunspots dataset](https://datasets.datadrivendiscovery.org/d3m/datasets/-/tree/266c67f2b9e9f8494fc1e4d0e3c137626354b084/56_sunspots/56_sunspots_dataset/tables).

I want to convert column 'year' in integer e.g. 1992 to datetime format then find the time delta and eventually compute total seconds (cumulative) to represent the time index column of a time series.

I am trying to use the following code but I get the error

> TypeError: dtype datetime64[ns] cannot be converted to timedelta64[ns]

```
sunspots_df['year'] = pd.to_timedelta(pd.to_datetime(sunspots_df['year'], format='%Y') ).dt.total_seconds()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pandas.Timedelta` ["[r]epresents a duration, the difference between two dates or times."](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html) So you're trying to get Python to tell you the difference between a particular datetime and...nothing. That's why it's failing.

If it's important that you store your index this way (and there may be better ways), then you need to pick a *start datetime* and compute the difference to get a `timedelta`.

For example, this code...

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [1990,1991,1992]})
diff = (pd.to_datetime(df['year'], format='%Y') - pd.to_datetime('1990', format='%Y'))\
    .dt.total_seconds()
```

...returns a series whose values are seconds from January 1st, 1990. You'll note that it doesn't invoke `pd.to_timedelta()`, because it doesn't need to: the result of the subtraction is automatically a `pd.timedelta` column.